# GroupBy array of objects to new array and sum value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a array like this in below, What I'm trying is seperating objects to new array by grouping two values.

**Array:**

```
[
 {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 11194.55,
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 60.2,
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "C"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202004",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 4674.59,
    "type": "D"
  }
]
```

Result should be like this;

**Output**

```
[
 [
  {
   "year": "202003",
   "cost": 11194.55,
   "type": "A"
  }
 ],
 [ 
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 60.2,
    "type": "B"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "C"
  }
 ],
 [
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 1494.24,     // sum of the COST value when year and type same.
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
     "year": "202004",
     "cost": 4674.59,
     "type": "D"
  }
 ]
];
```

**What I've tried**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
let aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(data)
            .GroupBy("$.type", "$.year",
                function (key, g) {
                    return {
                        label: key,
                        value: g.Sum("$.cost"),
                    }
                })
            .ToArray();
```

How can I group this data like this? Is there any library or a function to do this? I couldn't find yet.
Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Use reduce method and find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your initial array and the output you wanted to get, below are the examples that result in exactly the same structure as per your question - **an array of arrays of objects**

---

One way with `find` & `for of loop`:

```js
let arr = [
 {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 11194.55,
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 60.2,
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "C"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202004",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 4674.59,
    "type": "D"
  }
]

let sortedArray = []
for (let [index, el] of arr.entries()) {
  if(sortedArray.find(elInner => (elInner[0].type === el.type && elInner[0].year !== el.year))) {
    sortedArray.find(elInner => elInner[0].type === el.type).push(arr[index])
  }else if (sortedArray.find(elInner => (elInner[0].type === el.type && elInner[0].year == el.year))) {
    sortedArray.find(elInner => (elInner[0].type === el.type && elInner[0].year == el.year))[0].cost += arr[index].cost
  }else {
    sortedArray.push([el])
  }
}
console.log(sortedArray)
```

---

and another "cleaner" way with `reduce` & `map`

```js
let arr = [
 {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 11194.55,
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 60.2,
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "C"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202004",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 4674.59,
    "type": "D"
  }
]

let sortedArray = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const key = obj.type, year = obj.year
  !!acc[key] 
  ? (!!acc[key][year] ? acc[key][year].cost += obj.cost : acc[key][year] = obj) 
  : (acc[key] = [], acc[key][year] = obj)
    return acc
}, [])

sortedArray = Object.values(sortedArray).map((val) => Object.values(val))

console.log(sortedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` in order to accumulate the cost.

```js
const data = [
  {
    year: '202003',
    cost: 11194.55,
    type: 'A',
  },
  {
    year: '202003',
    cost: 60.2,
    type: 'B',
  },
  {
    year: '202003',
    cost: 747.12,
    type: 'C',
  },
  {
    year: '202003',
    cost: 747.12,
    type: 'D',
  },
  {
    year: '202004',
    cost: 747.12,
    type: 'D',
  },
  {
    year: '202003',
    cost: 4674.59,
    type: 'D',
  },
];

const final = data.reduce((result, current) => {
  const key = `${current.year}-${current.type}`;
  result[key] = result[key] || {...current, cost: 0};
  result[key].cost += current.cost;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(final).map(item => ([item])));
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution but I'm also trying to add this types different arrays. This shouldn't be like a single array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: In my output example all types are added like arrays, not like object in a single array

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `linq.js`, every callback execution accumulates the data if there's matching `year` and `type` or adds a copy of an object to an array which is returned from the function:

```js
let data = [
 {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 11194.55,
    "type": "A"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 60.2,
    "type": "B"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "C"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202004",
    "cost": 747.12,
    "type": "D"
  },
  {
    "year": "202003",
    "cost": 4674.59,
    "type": "D"
  }
];

let aggregatedObject = data.reduce((acc,cur) => {
   let prev = acc.find(x => x.year === cur.year && x.type === cur.type);
   if(!prev){
       acc.push([{...cur}]);
   } else {
       prev.cost += cur.cost;
   }
   return acc;
}, []);

console.log(aggregatedObject);
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I'm also trying to add this objects to different arrays not in same array of objects. [ [ ], [ ] ] like this. When types are different it should be an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a joined key with `linq` as forth parameter and a combined object for getting a summed value.

```js
var data = [{ year: "202003", cost: 11194.55, type: "A" }, { year: "202003", cost: 60.2, type: "B" }, { year: "202003", cost: 747.12, type: "C" }, { year: "202003", cost: 747.12, type: "D" }, { year: "202004", cost: 747.12, type: "D" }, { year: "202003", cost: 4674.59, type: "D" }],
    result = Enumerable
        .From(data)
        .GroupBy(
            null,
            null,
            "{ year: $.year, cost: $$.Sum('$.cost'), type: $.type }",
            "$.year + '|' + $.type"
        )
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, it need some improvement. Such as types should be in different array.